# Can't install/update heroku toolbelt - heroku-pipelines

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, heroku

I'm having problems updating with heroku toolbelt (on Ubuntu x64).

Whatever heroku command I try to run, heroku toolbelt will try to update itself and the update always fails with this output:

```
$ heroku
heroku-cli: Installing Toolbelt v4... done
For more information on Toolbelt v4: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-cli
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies... done
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 ▸    Error reading plugin: heroku-pipelines
 ▸    exit status 1
 ▸    module.js:327
 ▸        throw err;
 ▸        ^
 ▸    
 ▸    Error: Cannot find module 'heroku-pipelines'
 ▸        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
 ▸        at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
 ▸        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
 ▸        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
 ▸        at [eval]:2:15
 ▸        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
 ▸        at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
 ▸        at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
 ▸        at node.js:611:27
 ▸        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 ▸    Error reading plugin: heroku-pipelines
 ▸    exit status 1
 ▸    module.js:327
 ▸        throw err;
 ▸        ^
 ▸    
 ▸    Error: Cannot find module 'heroku-pipelines'
 ▸        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
 ▸        at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
 ▸        at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
 ▸        at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
 ▸        at [eval]:2:15
 ▸        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
 ▸        at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:6:22)
 ▸        at Module._compile (module.js:397:26)
 ▸        at node.js:611:27
 ▸        at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
 !    error getting commands pid 8898 exit 1
```

I've removed my ~/.heroku, I've apt-get remove --purge heroku*, and still it just fails.

I'm not that familiar with node.js to understand what kind of problem this is or if it even is a node.js problem at all.. Does anyone have a clue? Thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing same issue now, while yesterday I was having no problem; seems to be a temporal issue?

Comment: Now they are dealing with this https://status.heroku.com/

Comment: I'm the CLI maintainer, the incident has a summary describing what happened. Feel free to reach out to me if you have more questions. https://status.heroku.com/incidents/851

Comment: Working for me now.  5.21pm PT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Known Issue: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/851

**Issue**

> Our engineers are investigating issues with the Heroku CLI. Customers
>   may be seeing failures referencing "Error reading plugin:
>   heroku-pipelines".